# client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe issue while running jenkins pipeline from long time

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I was running jenkins pipeline code and after some time in console logs given client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

I have checked server firewall rules and checked connection using keypair, these are fine.

Comment: Can you include more information? Like the relevant section of the log or your pipeline configuration?

Answer (score -1):

pipeline {

```
stages {
    stage('Create EC2 Instance-Run Ansible command-Terminate EC2 Instance') {
        steps {
            script {
            sshagent(['zocia-rds-backup-ssh-key'])
                {       
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
    
                ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@X.X.X.X "bash -c ' sudo chmod 777 /etc/ssh/sshd_config && echo "TCPKeepAlive yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && echo "ClientAliveInterval 120" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && echo "ClientAliveCountMax 30" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && sudo systemctl restart sshd'"
        
                '''
                }
            } 
        }
    }             
}
```

}

Method 1:Prevent SSH timeout on the server side

$ vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

TCPKeepAlive yes

ClientAliveInterval 120

ClientAliveCountMax 30

$ sudo systemctl restart sshd

notes:

This will make the server send the clients a “null packet” every 120 seconds and not disconnect them until the client have been inactive for 30 intervals (120 seconds * 30 = 3600 seconds = 1 hours).

(or)
These settings will make the SSH server send a null packet to the other side every 120 seconds (2 minutes), and give up if it doesn’t receive any response after 30 tries, at which point the connection is likely to have been discarded anyway.

Method 2:Prevent SSH timeout on the client side (example: jenkins -----)

$ vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

TCPKeepAlive yes

ServerAliveInterval 120

ServerAliveCountMax 30

$ sudo systemctl restart sshd

notes:

This will send a “null packet” every 120 seconds on your SSH connections to keep them alive.
(or)

These settings will make the SSH client send a null packet to the other side every 120 seconds (2 minutes), and give up if it doesn’t receive any response after 30 tries, at which point the connection is likely to have been discarded anyway.

Comment: Please add rationale/explanation: How and why does this answer your question? And please check: Does it contain duplicate content or what is the specific difference? Perhaps it becomes more readable by editing it and removing any duplicate information.